# Iterate through multiple variables (or whole matrix) in Julia

Tags: arrays, matrix, optimization, multidimensional-array, julia

I have a 5 dimensional array want to do a calculation for each field and depending on the result fill each field either with 'true' or 'false'. Now I am wondering if there is a fast way of doing so without using 5 'nested' loops.
Thanks for your help

Edit: 
Sorry that the question wasn't clear.  I need to do calculations with 5 different variables and I have check each possible combination. 
My current approach is this:

```
while i<10
    while j<10
        while k < 10
            while l<10
                while m <10 
                    #some calculation which returns true or false
                    A[i,j,k,l,m]=f(i, j, k, l, m);
                m+=1;
                end
            l+=1;
            end
        k +=1;
        end
    j+=1; 
    end
i+=1; 
end
```

where A is my array. Now I am wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this. 
Sorry, I hope it is more clarified now.

Comment: Given the comments below I would recommend that you give a more precise what you actually want to achieve (preferably giving an example code that does the computation you want).

Comment: You need to provide some of the details of your program. *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: If `f` is the function that you want to apply to each element in an array, `A`, then you can get what you want by using dot-broadcasting: `B = f.(A)`. `f` should be a function that returns either `true` or `false`. Now, `B` is an array of the same size and shape as `A`, containing boolean values. For some cases, like "is the value greater than zero", you can just write `B = A .> 0`.

Comment: Hmm. OK, so you want the calculation to depend on the tuple of indices, not on the value of the array?

Comment: This question now seems clear and specific enough to me. Using `CartesianIndices` as suggested by @BogumiłKamiński is a good approach. Here's an example of what you want: `B = [f(ind.I...,) for ind in CartesianIndices(A)]`.

Comment: @DNF exactly. r

Comment: @DNF, does [ind in CartesianIndeces(A)] produce all possible tuples like (1,1,1,2,3) or something similar? If so, could I use f(ind) straight away? Or what exactly does [ind.I] mean?

Comment: It doesn't _quite_ produce tuples, but something very similar. `ind.I` or `Tuple(ind)` gives you a tuple, so if you want `f` to work directly on a tuple, you don't need to splat.

Comment: Thanks for you help! It works just the way I need it to and is much much shorter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CartesianIndices` function for example like this:

```
julia> x = Array{Tuple}(undef, 2,2,2,2,2);

julia> for idx in CartesianIndices(x)
       x[idx] = Tuple(idx)
       end

julia> x
2×2×2×2×2 Array{Tuple,5}:
[:, :, 1, 1, 1] =
 (1, 1, 1, 1, 1)  (1, 2, 1, 1, 1)
 (2, 1, 1, 1, 1)  (2, 2, 1, 1, 1)

[:, :, 2, 1, 1] =
 (1, 1, 2, 1, 1)  (1, 2, 2, 1, 1)
 (2, 1, 2, 1, 1)  (2, 2, 2, 1, 1)

[:, :, 1, 2, 1] =
 (1, 1, 1, 2, 1)  (1, 2, 1, 2, 1)
 (2, 1, 1, 2, 1)  (2, 2, 1, 2, 1)

[:, :, 2, 2, 1] =
 (1, 1, 2, 2, 1)  (1, 2, 2, 2, 1)
 (2, 1, 2, 2, 1)  (2, 2, 2, 2, 1)

[:, :, 1, 1, 2] =
 (1, 1, 1, 1, 2)  (1, 2, 1, 1, 2)
 (2, 1, 1, 1, 2)  (2, 2, 1, 1, 2)

[:, :, 2, 1, 2] =
 (1, 1, 2, 1, 2)  (1, 2, 2, 1, 2)
 (2, 1, 2, 1, 2)  (2, 2, 2, 1, 2)

[:, :, 1, 2, 2] =
 (1, 1, 1, 2, 2)  (1, 2, 1, 2, 2)
 (2, 1, 1, 2, 2)  (2, 2, 1, 2, 2)

[:, :, 2, 2, 2] =
 (1, 1, 2, 2, 2)  (1, 2, 2, 2, 2)
 (2, 1, 2, 2, 2)  (2, 2, 2, 2, 2)

The code stores in an entry `x[a,b,c,d,e]` a tuple `(a,b,c,d,e)`.
```

Comment: So this o one gives me all the possibilities I can have right? Is there a way to read out each 'coordinate' to do calculations?

Comment: @Tschaix You can use tuple unpacking: `v, w, x, y, z = Tuple(idx)`.

Comment: You can also index into `idx` as if it were a tuple, e.g. `idx[1]` will give you first dimension, `idx[2]` second etc. In particular, as it was noted above by @DNF you can write something like `x .= f.(CartesianIndices(x)` to fill `x` in place assuming that you write `f` in such a way that it accepts `CartesianIndex` - then you should unpack it inside the function or write something like `x .= (idx -> f(Tuple(idx)...)).(CartesianIndices(x)` to perform unpacking without modifying `f` if it accepts 5 arguments (again - all happening in place).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same kind of operations as you'd do on a 1-Dimensional matrix.

```
julia> A = rand(4,4,4,4,4);^C

julia> for (i, v) in enumerate(A)
         if v > 0.5 
           A[i] = 0
         end
       end
```

Also, somthing like:

```
   julia>map!(x->x>.5, A, A)
```

Also if the original Array is of some type other than `Bool` I'd suggest you use a different matrix to assign the result values for type stability.

Comment: `enumerate` will return linear index for array `A` as a first value in a tuple. I understood that @Tschaix needed a Cartesian index to know for each entry of the array what is its index in each dimension and calculate `true`/`fales` based on this location (and not on the value stored in an arrary).

Comment: He said "calculation for each field". I understood that as using the value stored in the array. Not sure now that I've read it again.

Comment: We will see when the question is clarified :).

Comment: Indeed. Also in your answer would `eachindex` in place of `CartesianIndices` be more readable?

Comment: You can put `eachindex` in my answer but then you will get tuples containing linear index of each cell, like 1,2,3,4,5 ... without information about each dimension.

Comment: Ah yes, `a UnitRange if all inputs have fast linear indexing, a CartesianRange otherwise.` from the doc.

Comment: I excuse my wording, Bogumol Kaminski is correct. I need to know the position for my calculations

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)